# Routing does not recognize modules for my sbt-multimodule project in Play 2 (code and error mesage inside)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am writing a modular application using Play 2 and decided to create sbt components as modules for the bigger framework. The application structure looks like this:

```
project
- build.sbt
- app
  - controllers
  - models
- bin
- conf
  - application.conf
  - routes
- modules
  - index
     - app
       - controllers
       - models
     - conf
       - index.routes
     - project
     - build.sbt
  - register
     - app
       - controllers
       - models
     - conf
       - register.routes
     - project
     - build.sbt
```

The configuration of `build.sbt` is:

```
name := """project"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


lazy val index = project.in(file("modules/index"))
lazy val register = project.in(file("modules/register"))

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
               .dependsOn(index,register).aggregate(index,register)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

This is how `conf/routes` looks like

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~



# Homepage
GET      /               controllers.HomeController.homepage

#Application
->    /index    index.Routes
# currently I'm only trying to get the first module to work
```

And this is my `index.routes`

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page

GET     /                  controllers.index.Application.list()
```

However everytime I try any http request I get essentially

```
[error] /home/.../project/conf/routes:12: not found: value index
[error] ->    /index    index.Routes
[error] /home/.../project/conf/routes:12: not found: value index
[error] ->    /index    index.Routes
[error] /home/.../project/conf/routes:12: not found: value index
[error] ->    /index    index.Routes
[error] three errors found
[error] (root/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application - 

! @715gad4do - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[not found: value index]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

I have tried to find the correct routing method but from everything I've researched all day this is the correct method to access sbt submodules through the primary Play App but for some reason it doesnt work for me. What could be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who ever encounters a similar problem: the trick is to write at the top of the 'module.routes` file (module being the name of whatever submodule you have) :

```
# MODULE Routes
```